# how to use the environment variable in shared module of BFF architecture nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, serverless-framework, shared-module, backend-for-frontend

I have a util class which is shared to the UI. In this setup all the **models** are in the **dist** folder when the project is built and the same is shared to the UI and other microservices.

example:

```
import { someModel } from 'models/sharedModels'

class MyUtil {
  static isTrueOrFalse(a: string, b:string): boolean {

     if(something === 'abc' && process.env.SOMETHING === 'xyz'){
         return true;
      }

  }
```

with the above changes my project is deployed as a microservice in serverless framework. lets say the name and version is `some-project@1.2.3`

Now in my Angular UI, I installed this package and use it to define types etc. The model is shared by backend and available for other services, UI to use and comply with the structure.

I have a toggle in UI, that sets to yes or no through `onclick` using the `MyUtil.isTrueOrFalse` function.

ex: `import { MyUtil } from 'some-project';`

`process.env.SOMETHING` used in the `MyUtil.isTrueOrFalse` function is not recognized in the UI. Is there a way to use env variable in shared modules? If not, please suggest possible alternatives.